# dynamic multiple checkbox react native hooks

Tags: react-native, react-functional-component

i want to make it on react native Hooks, how to convert class to functional component ( hooks ), this is the sample with class component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, CheckBox, TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native';
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Dts:["Banana","Apple","Mango","Watermelon"],
      data: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    let Temp=this.state.Dts
    let FormatData=[]
    for(let i=0;i<Temp.length;i++){
      FormatData.push(
        {
          id:i,
          key:Temp[i],
          checked:false
        }
      )
    }
    this.setState({ data:FormatData})
  }
  onchecked(id) {
    const data = this.state.data
    const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
    data[index].checked = !data[index].checked
    this.setState(data)
  }
  renderFruits() {
    return this.state.data.map((item, key) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: 'center', }} key={key} onPress={() => { this.onchecked(item.id) }}>
          <CheckBox value={item.checked} onValueChange={() => { this.onchecked(item.id) }} />
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{item.key}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  }
  getSelectedFruits() {
    var keys = this.state.data.map((t) =>  t.key )
    var checks = this.state.data.map((t) => t.checked)
    let Selected = []
    for(let i=0;i<checks.length;i++){
      if(checks[i]==true){
        Selected.push(keys[i])
      }
    }
    alert(Selected)
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <>
        {this.renderFruits()}       
        <View>
          <Button onPress={() => { this.getSelectedFruits() }} title="check"/>
        </View>
        </>
    );
  }
}
```

i want to get value if selected with click button submit, like the sample with hooks and how to get value for all selected

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but here is the version:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, CheckBox, TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native';


const App = (props) => {

    const [Dts, setDts] = useState(["Banana","Apple","Mango","Watermelon"])
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setData(Dts.map((element, index) => {
            return {
                id: index,
                key: element,
                checked: false
            }
        }))
    }, [])

    const onChecked = (id) => {
        const data = [...data]
        const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
        data[index].checked = !data[index].checked
        setData(data)
    }
    
    const renderFruits = () => {
        return data.map((item, key) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: 'center', }} key={key} onPress={() => { onChecked(item.id) }}>
                    <CheckBox value={item.checked} onValueChange={() => { onChecked(item.id) }} />
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{item.key}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    }

    const getSelectedFruits = () => {
        var keys = data.map((t) =>  t.key )
        var checks = data.map((t) => t.checked)
        let selected = []
        for(let i=0 ; i<checks.length ; i++){
            if(checks[i]==true){
                selected.push(keys[i])
            }
        }
        alert(selected)
    }
    return (
        <>
        {renderFruits()}       
        <View>
            <Button onPress={() => { getSelectedFruits() }} title="check"/>
        </View>
        </>
    );
}

export default App
```

Comment: thank you, i have tested. it can work if this part is replaced with ```const onChecked = (id) => {
        const datax = [...data]
        const index = datax.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
        datax[index].checked = !datax[index].checked
        setData(datax)
    }```  but how to make for one checkbox that we can select all. I have not understood